# Could not launch app Error : remote gdb server ios 7 Xcode 5

Tags: ios7, message, xcode5

I'm getting "Could not launch abc.app : not connected to remote gdb server" message at times while running application in Xcode 5 for iOS 7. What is this message and why does it occurs?

[image]

Comment: is this a PhoneGap App ?

Comment: @BalramTiwari Nope this is purely developed in iOS (native app).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is using phoneGap deploy. If so then kindly refer the support of `lldb` on phoneGap deploys [here](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/5)
The `gdb` support has been removed.

For more detail on patch refer [here](https://gist.github.com/shazron/6517269)